# Image loading from FXML and native packaging

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have some issues with loading images for tabs in a tabpane (buttons etc.)  from a fxml file when exported as native package for osx.

This code works fine when starting from eclipse but all images are gone when exporting the application as native package.

```
<BorderPane stylesheets="@../my.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="app.view.MainController">  
   <center>  
      <TabPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">  
        <tabs>  
          <Tab fx:id="projectsTab" closable="false">  
            <content>  
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0">  
                     <children>  
                        <fx:include source="main/ProjectView.fxml" />  
                     </children>  
              </AnchorPane>  
            </content>  
               <graphic>  
                  <ImageView fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="30.0" opacity="0.5" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">  
                     <image>  
                        <Image url="@../../../resources/images/ic_list_black_48dp_1x.png" />  
                     </image>  
                  </ImageView>  
               </graphic>  
          </Tab>
```

Using this code, work also when exported as native package but I would like to do it the fxml way.

```
private void initialize() {  
    projectsTab.setGraphic(createTabImage("/images/ic_list_black_48dp_2x.png"));    
}  

private ImageView createTabImage(String pathToImage) {  
     ImageView imgView = new ImageView(new Image(this.getClass().getResource(pathToImage).toExternalForm()));  
     imgView.setFitWidth(30);  
     imgView.setFitHeight(30);  
     imgView.setOpacity(0.5);  
     return imgView;  
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `resources` is usually just a folder in the source structure, i.e. it is not exported to build. You probably need `url="@../../images/ic_list_black_48dp_1x.png"`. If that doesn't work, check the content of the generated jar file (you can just do `jar tf jarfile.jar` from the command line).

Comment: That works perfectly.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most IDE setups, the `resources` folder itself is not exported when the project is compiled, but its contents are deployed to the root of the classpath. You haven't shown in your question where the FXML file is in relation to the image, but you probably need

```
url="@../../images/ic_list_black_48dp_1x.png"
```